# grep adds new line if splitted by groovy?

Tags: java, bash, jenkins, groovy

My goal is to get the names of x .conf files in a directory called "conf". My code looks like this:

```
commandOutput = sshCommand remote: getRemote(), command: getPathCmd(type) + "cd conf; ls | grep '.conf' | grep -Eo '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'"
def instances = commandOutput.split("\n") as String[]
return instances
```

If i print the variable  `commandOutput` (with two files in the directory) it shows me:

```
name1
name2
```

But when i make a for loop to print every slot of the array, i get this:

```
name1
*empty line*
```

and

```
name2
```

I checked `commandOutput[0]` with `.endsWith("\n")` and returned `false` so i dont know where the new line is coming from.
Is there an obvious reason for that behaviour?

Edit: It also happens here:

```
command = getPathCmd(type) + getScript(type, "status") + "| grep -Eo '[0-9]{4,5}' | sort -u | grep -v '${params.xyID}\\|" + globalID + "'"
try{
    commandOutput = sshCommand remote: getRemote(), command: command
    def PIDs = commandOutput.split("\n") as String[]
    return PIDs
    
}
catch(Exception e){
    println("XY")
    return "XY"
}
```

Print of `commandOutput`:

```
1234
5678
```

For loop print of `PIDs`:

```
1234
*empty line*
```

and

```
5678
```

Answer (score 1):

`stringXY = stringXY.replaceAll("[\\\r\\\n]+","");` did the trick. It replaces all new lines.

`tr '\n' '\0'` as suggested in this thread wouldn't work here, because it would be harder to find out where one name ends and the next one starts.